How to resolve 'invalid hostname for this tenancy' error when accessing Microsoft Graph API for multi-tenant app registration?
I have a multi-tenant app registration in Azure AD with permissions to Sites.Selected to use the Microsoft Graph API for reading/writing to SharePoint sites. Tenant B has successfully given admin consent through the generated admin consent link, resulting in an enterprise application in Tenant B. However, while I can access sites in Tenant A using the app registration, I receive an 'invalid hostname for this tenancy' error when trying to access sites in Tenant B.
How can I resolve this issue to access sites in Tenant B using the Microsoft Graph API?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
I tried calling "/sites/{hostName}:{serverRelativePath}" microsoft graph endpoint using a site from Tenant B which resulted in this error:
{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid hostname for this tenancy","innerError":{"date":"2024-07-04T08:03:02","request-id":"22ceb0ec-b377-4086-91ec-610ed637413f","client-request-id":"22ceb0ec-b377-4086-91ec-610ed637413f"}}}

Do you try to use the site name ? Or site ID ? You should try with the ID

If I use the site ID or site name i get a 404 not found, so for some reason the app reg is not able to find the site in the external tenant, i'm not even sure whether this is possible fyi

Yes it is possible, are you making use of Client Credential flow?

Create a Multi-Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application in TenantA and granted Microsoft Graph Sites.Selected API permission:

In TenantB, created a Service Principal and granted admin consent:
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId <AppIDOfTenantAApp>


After Grant Admin Consent, permissions are granted to the TenantB Enterprise application:

As you are making use of Client Credential flow, you must set up an app-only principal with tenant permissions:

Sites.Selected API permission allows access only to the selected sites.
Hence you need to grant access app access to the site you want to access.

Navigate to https://TenantBDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx and sign in with TenantB user. Pass the TenantAAppID and give access by using the XML request:
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>


Click on create and Trust it:

Generate access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:TenantAAppID
client_secret:TenantAClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


Now, I am able to successfully access TenantB site using TenantA  Microsoft Entra ID application:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/TenantBDomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/SiteName:/


If still the issue persists, make sure to pass Site ID instead of Site name to the API call you are passing.
If you do not want to grant permissions in the Add-in to allow Full Access to the application, then refer this SO Thread by me.

I'm going to try it out now it might take a while, but there is still a part that is confusing to me in the Generate Access Token section you meantion client_secret: TenantBClientSecret but in the image below you have it in red text saying TenantAClientSecret

It was a typo, its TenantAClientSecret only updated the answer

I am unable to get an access token using the tenant B URL, I get back a bad request I'm trying to extend the logging now to find out more details

Did you create service principal in TenantB?

With my tenant B admin i opened an admin consent url for the application in tenant A, which asked me to give admin consent to the application to use Sites.Selected permissions, after i consented an Enterprise Application appeared in tenant B with the same name as the application in tenant A, is that what you mean by creating a service principal in tenant B?

Yes that is what I meant

On monday I will have another go at this I will try to reproduce it in exactly the way you described and see if I can get that working, il let you know what the results are, thank you for the help so far!

@SelmirAljic Any update on the issue?

Just got it to work locally using the approach you mentioned, now I can slowly figure out why it is not working in production. Thanks you for the help it is greatly appreciated!

Glad to know that it helped:)
