Multi-Tenant Access Issues for OneDrive/SharePoint via Microsoft Graph API
In this scenario:
"XX" represents our application.
"YY" represents the client’s application.
The client has registered an app in their "YY" tenant in Azure AD and provided it with the necessary Graph API permissions (such as Sites.FullControl.All or Files.ReadWrite.All).
Our app (XX) must receive consent from an admin in the "YY" tenant. The admin needs to approve our app (XX) to access their resources.
Once consent is granted, our app (XX) will be authorized to access resources in the "YY" tenant.
The client (YY) must grant our app (XX) permission to access OneDrive or SharePoint resources in their tenant. This is done by making a Microsoft Graph API POST request to /permissions.
This step ensures that our app (XX) can access specific resources in the client’s (YY) tenant.
Once the permissions are granted, we can use our app's (XX) client ID, secret, and tenant to fetch documents from the client’s (YY) OneDrive/SharePoint.
Currently, we have generated an access token using our app (XX) credentials, which should have permission to access resources in the client’s (YY) tenant. In spite of this, it is not functioning properly, and we are required to register two applications in the client environment with two distinct permissions.
Are we missing something over here?

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78707204/how-to-resolve-invalid-hostname-for-this-tenancy-error-when-accessing-microsof/78710389#78710389

+1 to the comment above. You can also check the token and decode for the right permissions and confirm that they are correct using https://jwt.ms/ , Make sure that you are using the correct tenant ID while making a request.  Ensure that when you are accessing resources in another tenant (YY), you  use their tenant ID, not yours (XX). So the authority url should look something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId-of-YY}

working on it, will let you know

Sure @PoojaParmar

Any update on the issue?

To access OneDrive or SharePoint resources in another tenant, check the below:
Created a Microsoft Entra ID application in TenantA and granted API permissions:

In the TenantB, created a service principal and granted admin consent:
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId <AppIDOfTenantAApp>


Grant permission to the selected sites (optional):
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesIdofTenantB}/permissions
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "roles": ["write"],
  "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": "TenantAAppID",
      "displayName": "SharePointApp"
    }
  }]
}


Generate the access token using TenantB tenant ID:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:TenantAAppID
client_secret:TenantAClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


Make sure the roles are present in the access token:

Now make use of this access token to fetch documents in TenantB:
I am able to get drive of the site successfully of TenantB:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drives/bDriveID


You can refer this MsDoc for the APIs based on your requirement.
Reference:
sharepoint - How to resolve 'invalid hostname for this tenancy' error when accessing Microsoft Graph API for multi-tenant app registration? - Stack Overflow by me
